# Hard-hard and soft-soft acid/base interactions

Tags: hsab

How does one conclude if a given compound or a complex is a hard or soft acid or base?

What are the factors that contribute to hard-hard, soft-soft, soft-hard, and hard-soft interactions?

Comment: This could be helpful: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/10273/hardness-and-softness-are-terms-used-to-describe-which-aspect-of-acidic-behaviou?rq=1