# Hard and Soft Acid and Bases in terms of HOMO and LUMO

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, hsab

It has been given in a book and on Wikipedia that:

> hard bases have highest-occupied molecular orbitals (HOMO) of low energy, and hard acids have lowest-unoccupied molecular orbitals (LUMO) of high energy.[7][8]
>
> soft bases have HOMO of higher energy than hard bases, and soft acids have LUMO of lower energy than hard acids. (However the soft-base HOMO energies are still lower than the soft-acid LUMO energies.)[7][8]

Let us consider the energy difference between HOMO and LUMO is given by $\Delta E$. Thus,
$$\Delta E (S-S)<\Delta E(H-S) < \Delta E (H-H)$$

Hence the hard-hard interaction should have been weaker than hard-soft, which is not the case. Please explain.

P.S.: I went through the reference (Meissler and Tarr) and [this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/10273/hardness-and-softness-are-terms-used-to-describe-which-aspect-of-acidic-behaviou/11055#11055) but could not find a satisfying explanation.

Comment: The idea is that hard-hard interactions also have a significant element of electrostatic attraction, which isn't accounted for by MO theory.

Comment: Can you please tell any formula that determines which path for interaction is the most feasible (say in terms of free energy)