# Why do large cations stabilise large anions and small cations stabilise small anions?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

I see this trend from enthalpy change of decomposition data, though I struggle to find a decent explanation for why.

Comment: Are you asking this with regards to the dissolution of inorganic salts?

Comment: related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/10273/hardness-and-softness-are-terms-used-to-describe-which-aspect-of-acidic-behaviou

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For more detailed info, search "cation-anion radius ratio" or "Pauling's rules". Below is my review of this idea.

This ratio is ${R_{C}/R_{A}}$ (C = cation, A=anion).

Small cation (I mean, **too small**) attracts anions in such a way that they come too close to each other and repulsive force comes into play. This happens when ratio is <0,155. So for larger anion, larger cation suits better. Ratio can be 0.155-1 for stable compounds, and this ratio also determines coordination number and type of void! (Check the picture below, recall that since <0.155 ratio is for unstable compounds, you have empty "example" line there).

[image]